How to trigger update from Blazor embedded page call
Sorry I don't know what it's called, but from a razor page (Files.razor) I embed another page using something like <AddFile ContainerID="@ID" DocType="3" />.  AddFile.razor is a utility method that allows the user to upload a file and add it to the list with id == @ID.  When Files.razor runs it loads the list of files.
The problem is the new file is uploaded in AddFile.razor but Files.razor doesn't include the new file until I close the page and reload it.
Is there a way for AddFile.razor to call back to Files.razor after a file's uploaded so Files.razor can add the file to it's collection?
Thanks for any help!

EventCallback

Do you have StateHasChanged in your codes for event handler like onuploaded?
